# CSS pre-processor perhaps?

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML / CSS site: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/LRUgt/)

Now it works fine on the original codepen but when I put it on jsfiddle it doesn't work. I notice it uses some techniques I havent seen in normal CSS, such as this:

```
&.fixed {
```

Can anyone tell me if this is why it isnt working in JSfiddle, and if this can be coded without having to add some sort of pre-processor?

Comment: Note, things change a bit when you change the CSS language to "SCSS" under the language options in jsFiddle.

Comment: In codepen, set CSS settings to none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LRUgt/1/)**

If it's like this:

```
nav{
  /*styles*/

  > p{
    /*styles*/
  }
}
```

All you need to do is re-write it so it's like this:

```
nav{
  /*styles*/
}

nav > span {
  /*styles*/
}
```

This:

```
&.active
```

would be:

```
nav.active{
  /*styles*/
}
```

but because it's in `span` in the code, it will be:

(original)

```
nav{
  /*styles*/

  > span{
    /*styles*/

    &.active{
      /*styles*/
    }
  }
}
```

(CSS)

```
nav{
  /*styles*/
}

nav > span{
  /*styles*/
}

nav > span.active{
  /*styles*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be coded without a preprocessor, the syntax is simply nested with the use of & indicating apply this selector conjoined with the parent selector (i.e. as well as the parent), so you can change your CSS to:

```
* {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
header {
    background:#CCEAF9;
    height:100px;
    padding:1em;
}
nav {
    background:#000;
    color:#FFF;
    height:50px;
    padding:0 1em;
    transition:0.3s;
}
nav > span {
    display:inline-block;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:1em;
    margin-right:1em;
    opacity:.5;
}
nav > span.active {
    opacity:1;
}
nav.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    opacity:0.6;    
}
.fixed + #navPlaceholder {
    height:50px;
}
section {
    height:600px;
    background:#EEE;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #DDD 0%, #FFF 100%);
    padding:1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone tell me if this is why it isnt working in JSfiddle

Because it isn't CSS

> and if this can be coded without having to add some sort of pre-processor?

Just duplicate whatever it is that the pre-processor would do.

Which is probably to take the ruleset out of the ruleset it is inside, and replace `&` with the selector for the ruleset you just removed it from.

e.g.

```
.foo { &.fixed { ... } }
```

becomes

```
.foo { }
.foo.fixed { ... }
```